# Python - Creating folder names based on argument values

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I am trying to create a function that would create a folder based on the values passed as arguments. The function has 2 arguments (one argument that stores the store name and the other argument that has a reference date). Given below is the function.

```
def sales_fn(name,date):
    path = "/Users/user/'%s'/{}"%(name).format(date)
```

I keep getting an error

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/Users/user/'store_name'{}"
```

Could anyone guide me where am I going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You're confusing the old `%` string formatting with `.format`, try to search online for documentation and examples that use `.format` you'll find plenty! Side-note: a path shouldn't contain quotes

Comment: A path can contain quotes if he thinks the username might contain spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange to use multiple types of string formatting like that. `%` is the old way, so just use `.format()`:

```
path = "/Users/user/'{}'/{}".format(name, date)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about **f-strings**, they are much more elegant-

```
path = "/Users/user/'%s'/{}"%(name).format(date)
```

to -

```
path = f"/Users/user/{name}/{date}"
```

NOTE: They will work only with Python 3.6+